# JanusGraph docker compose environment

Tags: docker-compose, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I'm trying to setup JanusGraph using docker compose using the following lines in a `docker-compose.yml` file

```
janusgraph:
    image: janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
    environment:
      JANUS_CONFIG_DIR: /conf
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cql
      gremlinserver.graphManager: org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager
      gremlinserver.channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WsAndHttpChannelizer
      gremlinserver.graphs.graph: conf/janusgraph-cql-server.properties
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: janusgraph_cassandra
      janusgraph.gremlin.graph: org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory
      janusgraph.graph.graphname: ConfigurationManagementGraph
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
      - solr
    ports:
      - 8182:8182
    networks:
      - janusgraph
    restart: always
    container_name: janusgraph
```

The build is running just ok, but the two configuration files (`janusgraph-server.yml`, `janusgraph-cql-server.properties`) remain unchanged. Is there something am I missing here?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I will say that setting up JanusGraph is really really hard!  I've been working all day at it and I cant get things to work. I downloaded the full distribution, unpacked it and then used mvn to test the examples. Even those test failed. It's very, very frustrating!

Comment: The files changed should be `"${JANUS_CONFIG_DIR}/janusgraph.properties"` and `"${JANUS_CONFIG_DIR}/janusgraph-server.yaml"` (as can be seen in [1]). Are these the ones you checked? And is there a reason why you changed `JANUS_CONFIG_DIR` and `gremlinserver.graphs.graph`?

[1]: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker/blob/9b2ddab3a07d37e2bd3cbb244efabb1f1bd921ea/0.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L21